# Diaries of Nicolas II

Tags: russia, russian-revolution

In a library of President Yeltsyn the originals of the diaries could be found. But they only cover the time until 1906. The printed editions of his diary cover his records until his last days in 1918. So, where are the originals of the diaries for the 1907-1918 period?

Comment: Are you sure about the library and the originals there? According to Russian Wikipedia all original writings of Nicolas' diary are stored in the so-called [Novoromanovsky archive](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Новоромановский_архив)

Comment: @user907860, I got this information from the website of Eltsyn Library, http://www.prlib.ru/en-us/Lib/pages/item.aspx?itemid=66453.

Comment: the reference has rather complicated annotations, but it definitely says about two editions of the diaries: one was published in Saint-Petersburg, in the library itself in 2012, a digital version and another was published in Berlin in 1923 (it is said that this is also a digital version). One of them are present in the library in a printed form (it is not clear to me which one). And then the ref. has the words: *The place of storage of the original: the Presidential Library*. But it looks to me, that the original in question is one of the mentioned editions, not the originals of the diaries

Comment: If "Eltsyn" was meant to refer to [Boris Yeltsin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Yeltsin) (as an answer below implies), I think it should be so edited. That is the standard accepted English/Latin-1 spelling of the man's name.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F_II), the originals of the diaries (50 notebooks, from 1882 to 1918) are stored in the State archive of the Russian Federation (fund 601), as a part of the so-called Novoromanovsky archive (i.e. the New Romanov archive). There is no mention about the Yeltsin library.